# Type Error in Promisifying Mongoose Connect

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, bluebird, chai

I tried to Promisify Mongoose connect by using bluebird, I need to reduce my callbacks so I used bluebird.But It gives me the error below.

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var jobModel = require('../models/job');

var Promise = require('bluebird');

function resetJobs() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    mongoose.connection.collections['jobs'].drop(resolve, reject);
  });
};

function findJobs(query) {
  return Promise.cast(mongoose.model('Job').find({}).exec());
};

var connectDB = Promise.promisify(mongoose.connect,mongoose);
describe('get jobs', function() {
  it('Should not be empty since jobs are seeded', function(done) {
    connectDB('mongodb://localhost/jobfinder').then(function() {
      resetJobs()
        .then(jobModel.seedJobs)
        .then(findJobs).then(function(jobList) {
          expect(jobList.length).to.be.at.least(1);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

But this gives me a error

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined
at Mongoose.connect (F:\MyProjects\JobFinder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:232:18)
at tryCatcher (F:\MyProjects\JobFinder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:11:23)
at ret (eval at <anonymous> (F:\MyProjects\JobFinder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promisify.js:184:12), <anonymous>:14:23)
at Context.<anonymous> (F:\MyProjects\JobFinder\test\jobs-data-spec.js:22:3)
```

The versions of packages I'm using as follows

```
"bluebird": "^3.1.1",
"express": "^4.13.4",
"mongoose": "^4.3.6"
```

Comment: It seems works well with the following codes `var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var connectDB = Promise.promisify(mongoose.connect, mongoose);

console.log(connectDB);`

Comment: It still works well, `var connectDB = Promise.promisify(mongoose.connect,mongoose);
console.log(connectDB);` I guess the `mongoose` module you required is not correct...

Comment: @zangw The package versions I'm using also added. Thank you for the help you given so far

Comment: I think it is not related to the version. you could debug it through `console.log(mongoose);` to check the value of `mongoose`, since the error shown `no connect method of mongoose`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am working on the same tutorial.
Bluebird changes the api in 3.0 from
// 2.x Promise.promisify(fn, ctx);
// 3.0  Promise.promisify(fn, {context: ctx});

I made the call change and the calls stopped throwing the errors.

See here for the Bluebird explanation:
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/new-in-bluebird-3.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, 1+ for sharing the link

Answer (score 2):

The following code seems to works for me.

```
var connectMongoose = Promise.promisify(mongoose.connect, {context: mongoose}); 
connectMongoose('MONGO_URL', mongoose)
 .then(..)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same tutorial as well, and here is what I did to resolve the issue.

```
npm uninstall bluebird
npm install --save bluebird@2.0
```

Then when you run your tests with `mocha` you should pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually promisify mongoose.connect, without using bluebird:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { promisify } = require('util');


const connectMongoose = promisify((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };
    const uri = 'mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>' +
        '@cluster0.iz4o8.mongodb.net/<DB-NAME>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
    try {
        mongoose.connect(uri, options, resolve);
    } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
    }
});


(async () => {
    try {
        await connectMongoose();
        console.log('connected to monoose! :)');
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error('could not connect to mongoose :(', err);
        process.exit(-1);
    }
})();
```